# Why int and long types are first-class and favored by C# and the runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, int, clr, long-integer

In **Numeric Types** topic in Chapter 2 (**C# 5.0 in a Nutshell**) I found this phrase:

[image]

Why *int* and *long* are first-class citizens and favored by both C# and the runtime? and, Why the other types are used for interoperability?

Comment: It really depends, what "other types" are you talking about? `uint` and `ulong`? Or `UIntPtr`? Or `Guid` or `String`?

Comment: @Mehrdad sbyte, short, byte, ushort, uint, ulong.

Answer (score 12):

Because of the way modern processors are constructed. 32-bit and 64-bit processors are especially optimized to handle 32-bit and 64-bit integers. This is called the [*word* size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29):

> Modern processors, including embedded systems, usually have a word size of 8, 16, 24, 32 or 64 bits, while modern general purpose computers usually use 32 or 64 bits.

This means that a processor can perform arithmetic with these types with more ease than it can the other types. A `byte` or `short`, despite theoretically taking up less space in memory, are still loaded into 32-bit or 64-bit registers on the processor (depending on the architecture).

Comment: This says nothing about `uint` and `ulong`.

Answer (score 2):

#### The preference of `int` and `long` over `uint` and `ulong` is ***completely arbitrary***.

There's no technical reason why unsigned integers would be harder to support than signed integers; if anything, *signed* integers would be harder to support in hardware.

Furthermore, "compatibility" isn't even a reason, because when .NET was designed, there was *nothing to stay compatible with*!

So signed types are preferred **because they felt like it**.
They could very well have designed the CLS to include unsigned integers, and it would've worked too.

Comment: Side note: I believe `int` behaves much more reasonably in normal range of values compared to `uint`: `int v = 4; int d = v - 10;` is easier to explain to most people compared to similar code with `uint`... so I don't think it is "completely arbitrary".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Language specifications aren't about intuition though, they're about portability. Removing unsigned integers doesn't improve the intuitiveness of signed integers...

Comment: Unsigned integers are still there, they just aren't part of the Common Language Specification because some languages that connect to .NET (including older versions of VB) didn't have unsigned integers so they wouldn't have been able to use methods with unsigned integer parameters.

Comment: @JKor: The CLS is just nonsense. There were no technical limitation to adding unsigned integers to VB (as is obvious in VB.NET). They just didn't feel like adding it so they didn't.

Comment: They did add it in newer versions.  I do agree that the CLS should have unsigned integers, but I also understand how not including it lowers the qualification barrier for new languages that target the CLR.

Comment: @JKor: The thing is, CLS-compliance doesn't mean anything whatsoever. If they had added it to the CLS, then VB wouldn't have been "CLS-compliant". Big deal, no one would care about the CLS anyway. Everything else would've been exactly the same anyway.

Comment: You're probably right.  I see where Microsoft was going, but I also agree with you; they could have had unsigned integers from the start.